# how to build iso8583 version 2003 message using openiso8583?

Tags: iso8583, openiso8583.net

As we know, iso8583 version 2003 indicates by mti 2xxx (ref: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8583#ISO_8583_version)

the question is how to create iso8583 message version 2003 with openiso8583?
I'm already set the property MessageType to Iso8583.MsgType._0800_NWRK_MNG_REQ (create netman message for example), what i'm expected is mti 2800 but the message return mti 0800.

it seem the default version used by iso8583net library is iso version 1987, cmiiw.

Comment: You may want to edit this for clarity. It looks like your question could be better phrased as directly asking how to construct the message using the openiso8583 library. Please avoid using lots of unnecessary contractions and acronyms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look through the code you'll see that `Iso8583.MsgType._0800_NWRK_MNG_REQ` is a constant int 0x800.  I recommend that you create your own `Iso8583Rev03` message and your own subclass MsgType where you put

```
public const int _2800_NWRK_MNG_REQ = 0x2800;
```

Then use that in your code.